# Is there a lodash function or a 'lodash way' to do a conditional _.map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming, lodash

So basically, I have an array of objects and I'd like to update only the objects in the array that satisfy a condition. I want to know if there's like a good functional way of solving that problem. Right now I'm using lodash. Here's and example:

```
var things = [
    {id: 1, type: "a", value: "100"}, 
    {id: 2, type: "b", value: "300"}, 
    {id: 3, type: "a", value: "100"}
];
var results = _.map(things, function (thing) { 
    if(thing.type === "a") {
        thing.value = "500";
    } 
    return thing;
});
// => results should be [{id: 1, type: "a", value: "500"}, {id: 2, type: "b", value: "300"}, {id: 3, type: "a", value: "500"}];
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need here to use `map` method.

You can use a simply `forEach` function by passing a **callback** function to it.

```
var results = _.forEach(things, function (thing) { 
  if(thing.type === "a") {
    thing.value = "500";
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just map the new objects with a condition inside of [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), without mutating the original object.

```js
var things = [{ id: 1, type: "a", value: "100" }, { id: 2, type: "b", value: "300" }, { id: 3, type: "a", value: "100" }],
    results = things.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, o.type === "a" && { value: 500 }));

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (or Lodash's equivalent) with a ternary that will create a new updated object if the type is `a` using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
var things = [
    {id: 1, type: "a", value: "100"}, 
    {id: 2, type: "b", value: "300"}, 
    {id: 3, type: "a", value: "100"}
];
var result = things.map(function (thing) { 
    return thing.type === 'a' ? Object.assign({}, thing, { value: 500 }) : thing;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a little early, but with the [proposal for object rest spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) which is currently in stage-3 you could solve it like this:

```js
const things = [
    {id: 1, type: "a", value: "100"}, 
    {id: 2, type: "b", value: "300"}, 
    {id: 3, type: "a", value: "100"},
];
const result = things.map(e => e.type === 'a' ? {...e, value: 500 } : e);
console.log(result);
```